# formula to subtract pairs of cells - excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet which I want to: `E2=C3-C2`, then `E3=C5-C4`, `E4=C7-C6` etc for lots of cells:

[image]

So I am looking for a formula which I can drag down which minuses values in pairs rather than consecutively.

I tried SUM(OFFSET) but only added values, not minus.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use a formula in `E2`, then try:

```
=INDEX(C:C,ROW()*2-1)-INDEX(C:C,ROW()*2-2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of using `OFFSET` can be made to work. In `E2` put

```
=OFFSET($C$1,2*ROW()-2,0)-OFFSET($C$1,2*ROW()-3,0)
```

and copy down.

Comment: thank you, solution works! Wish I could accept both answers